# Применение потоков в java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Допустим есть задача с поиском суммы в списке. Решается элементарно

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
```

Почему, если список содержит очень большое количество элементов, то эту задачу следует решать с применением потоков? Нет же никакой разницы, с тем, если это будет выполнятся в одном потоке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, вы неправильно представляете, как будет выглядеть параллельная версия этой задачи.

Работать это будет в общих чертах так:

1. вначале нужно разделить задачу на части. В этом случае нужно поделить список, на части, которые будут обрабатываться потоками. (-)
2. обработка частей в отдельных потоках параллельно: суммирование каждой части списка в отдельном потоке (+).
3. слияние результатов параллельных потоков в финальный результат (-).

Факторы, которые делают алгоритм быстрее я пометил (+), а те, которые его замедляют - (-).

При достаточно большом списке выигрыш полученный за счет параллельной обработки на шаге 2 перевесит дополнительную работу (по сравнению с однопоточной версией) необходимую сделать на шагах 1 и 3.

Сбивать с толку еще может то, что в простом случае параллельная версия будет выглядеть очень похоже (но под капотом будет делать то, что описано выше):

```
list.parallelStream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum()
```

Comment: Да, примерно об этом думал, но в книге, в которой я этот пример увидел, поток был реализован точно также, как и исходный, из-за этого я запутался

Comment: Хм. Вряд ли так же как исходный, скорее всего использовался `parallelStream` вместо `stream`. Я добавил в ответ пример.